# One vs multiple checkboxes

Tags: grails, parameters

I want to have a number of `<g:checkBox name="bob" value="${i}" />` in a form and iterate through them in `params`:

```
def blah = params.bob.collect { Bob.get(it) }
```

It seems to work fine when there are multiple checkboxes present on the form and checked (`params.bob` is a `List` of some sort). However, if only one checkbox is presented on the form and checked `params.bob` is a `String` rather than a `List` with one `String` in it.

What is the best way to deal with this? I'm doing something like this at the moment:

```
if (params.bob instanceof String) {
    blah = [Bob.get(params.bob)]
}
else {
    blah = params.bob.collect { Bob.get(it) }
}
```

Is there a way to force `params` to make a `List` for `bob` so that I don't have to have this nasty `if`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried: `params.list('bob')` [see Handling Multi Parameters](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#typeConverters)